# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Installed selenium chromedriver and it shows this:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong version of chrome driver go to chrome://version in your chrome browser and take the chromedriver version that is equal to your chrome browser version.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=97.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=97.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 97

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=96.0.4664.93*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v96.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 96

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- [*ChromeDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).